# How to change the css in iframe which is inside the shadow root

Tags: css, iframe

Is there a way to change styles found in a iframe, which the iframe is in a shadow root?
I try a lot,However it just works on the element in shadow root but not in the inner iframe.

```js
<div class="outer">
  #shadow root(open)
    <iframe>
       <div class="inner"></div>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ufff it's a bit of late, but I think could be useful for anyone who find this question, in your shadow root is an open one, you could access to its nodes inside it by getting the shadow ref node and access to its nodes, so try the following code.

```
const shadowRootNode = document.querySelector('.outer');
let shadowIframe;
if (shadowRootNode.shadowRoot) { // it means it's an open shadow
  shadowIframe = shadowRootNode.shadowRoot.querySelector('iframe');
}
if (shadowIframe) {
  // then you can apply styles or add any attrs for the shadow iframe.
  shadowIframe.style = "";
}
```

I hope it could help anyone else and also you too :)